# How can I use C++ to sort an array alphabetically into a new array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, visual-studio-2015

I have an array called *g_Parameters* that I am looking to sort alphabetically in a new array called *g_SortedParameters*.

I have provided the code for the array.  I need to sort it alphabetically to use in a log, but without *g_Parameters* itself being sorted alphabetically as other code relies on the indexing as it stands.

```
const unsigned long ParamsCount = 6;
const TCHAR * const g_Parameters[ParamsCount] =
{ TEXT("AllowFatal"), TEXT("Variant"), TEXT("EnableLogs"),
  TEXT("AllowRescan"), TEXT("Path"), TEXT("Filter"),
};
```

I would appreciate any help with sorting this array into a new array. I'm happy to provide more information if it is required.

Comment: how about `std::sort` ?

Comment: The cleanest would be to copy the content of array with `std::copy` and sort the copy with `std::sort`, but I'm not sure how well is that working with winapi.

Comment: `std::partial_sort_copy()` can be used to copy and sort at the same time without modifying the original.

Comment: `ParamsCount = 3`? I would count 6 elements in array. but missing `{`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Typo on my part, thanks for pointing out.  Fixed!

Comment: Whenever you have a problem like this, your first step should be to browse through the list of algorithms provided by the standard library.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There really isn't any WinAPI here - granted, `TCHAR` is being used, but that's just either `char` or `wchar_t` so we're dealing with pure C-strings and wide C-strings

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`std::partial_sort_copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy) which, despite the name, can be used to sort a copy of an entire array without modifying the order of the original.

Demonstration:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
void print_array(const std::array<T, N> &ar) {
  for (const auto &elem : ar) {
    std::cout << elem << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::array<int, 5> orig = { 10, 8, 1, 4, 3 }, sorted;
  std::partial_sort_copy(orig.begin(), orig.end(), sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
  print_array(orig);
  print_array(sorted);
}
```

when compiled and run will print out

```
10 8 1 4 3 
1 3 4 8 10
```

Comment: However, you'll also need to teach predicates since the array contains C-strings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Or just tell OP to use `std::string` instead of whatever `TCHAR *` and `TEXT()` are. This is just to give him an idea of how to use the function. Adding a custom comparison function is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Perhaps as a bonus, but as it currently stands this answer is insufficient for the question posed. When they apply this solution, they will get the wrong answer. You _could_ leave the predicate as an exercise to the reader, but you should at least mention that the exercise exists.

Comment: @Shawn - "Or just tell OP to use std::string instead of whatever TCHAR * and TEXT() are." No.  These can't be changed like that and must remain as they are.